# ActionPerformed & ActionListener & implementing

Tags: java, eventhandler, implements

Getting error on line where HandlerClass implements ActionListener saying "Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
     tokens
    - Syntax error, insert '}' to complete Block"

What I've got wrong there ?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

private JTextField tf;
private JCheckBox boldbox;
private JCheckBox italicbox;

public Gui() {
    super("Hakuna Matata");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    tf = new JTextField("This is a sentence");
    tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    add(tf);

    boldbox = new JCheckBox("bold");
    italicbox = new JCheckBox("italicbox");
    add(boldbox);
    add(italicbox);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    boldbox.addActionListener(handler);
    italicbox.addActionListener(handler);
}
private HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Font font = null;
        if(boldbox.isSelected() && italicbox.isSelected())
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else if(boldbox.isSelected())
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
        else if(italicbox.isSelected())
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);

        tf.setFont(font);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close but off in implementing `ActionListener`, the correct method signature that you need to override is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event);
```

Please note the lowercase `a` in the start of the method name, as per the Java convention for all method names to start from lower case character.

**EDIT**

Also, your `HandlerClass` should be an inner `class`, so it should be declared as:

```
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

Please note that I added the `class` keyword before the `HandlerClass` name.
Also, I suggest that you rename it to a more appropriate class name, such as `Handler` instead of `HandlerClass`.

Comment: Why you're closing the header with semicolon ? There's a body after that.

Comment: He is referring to the `ActionListener` interface, which does not declare method body, just the header.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is a body in your implementation. I closed it because I specified how it is in the interface, which does not have an implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes. The first is as JChrist describes. To prevent this, you should have

```
@Override
```

before the method.

But the real mistake is you're missing a closing curly bracket at the end. You never close the Gui class.

Comment: I had a bracket there. Before I posted a question here I made sure that I'm not missing a semicolon. Didn't want to waste your time on a rookie mistake but I removed semicolon 'coz I was getting error saying get rid off it so I did despite I didn't understand why 'coz I was sure it should be there.